# navigate doesn't work in response HttpClient

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello Can Someone please explain to me why router.navigate ,doesn't work when it used in subscribe httpClient and how do it correctly

example:

in component:

```
 getResponse(){
    this.service.getRespone().subscribe((result) => {
      //do something with response
          this.router.navigate(['/secondcomponent']); //move after finish to secondComponent
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
      alert('Your access token has expired please login again to get a new one');
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    });
  }
```

in service:

```
public getResponse(): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.get<Response>(this.API_URL , {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.authtoken}`
      })
    })
  }
```

assume that request was send ,no error in console i tried with

```
this.router.navigate(['/login'], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute })
```

and with

```
  this.ngZone.run(() =>  this.router.navigate(['/']));
```

*EDIT

in app.modules i have defined my router and it

```
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},  <- i am here 
  {path: 'secondcomponent', component: SecondComponent}, <-want to go there if request is success
```

now in component(home)

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
 constructor(private service :Service,private userservice:UserService,private router: Router,private route:ActivatedRoute,private ngZone: NgZone)
```

}

Comment: What is the current route? And the injected router and it's import.

Comment: i edited question and add imports and  current route ^^^

Comment: Any error in the console? Did the  you set a break point to check that it goes through the navigate method?

Comment: I wrote  "no error in console" but if i change navigate to not exists path its show error about it so it go there but nothing happend

Comment: `//do something with response` - Could you please say what are you doing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try with navigatebyUrl

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/secondcomponent')
```

Also try to put a logger within the response section to ensure the response block is executed.